# How to aggregate data between two filters in Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation, kibana-6

I have two filters transfer* and transfer_failures. Each filter is the output of a database query using ES DB queries. I need to visualize a graph that aggregate monthly the number of transfer_failures/total transfers in the month.

Both have timestamp created field with the same format, but I wanna know how to plot table that uses two filters!

So suppose I have 40 total transfers on May 'should be calculated using the transfer* filter' and 10 transfer_failures 'should be calculated by the transfer_failure* filter' so the graph should blot 10/40=.25 on May supposing building a Vertical Bar.

I've some screenshots to show, but I am not allowed to post these here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter ratio aggregation on Visualize -> TSVB/Time Series Visual Builder if you want to calculate percentages using two filters.